# Xamarin Layout can't receive focus

Tags: forms, xamarin, layout, focus

I'm trying to create a compound view component in Xamarin Forms called FormElement which is composed of two labels and an Entry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StackLayout xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:Mynamespace;assembly=Mynamespace"
         x:Class="Mynamespace.Components.FormEntry">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label x:Name="formRequiredStar"
               IsVisible="{Binding IsRequired}"
               Text="*" TextColor="Red"
               FontSize="15"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               Margin="-12,0,0,0"
               HorizontalOptions="Start" />
        <Label x:Name="formLabel"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               Text="{Binding LabelText}"
               TextColor="{Binding LabelTextColor}"
               FontSize="{Binding LabelTextFontSize}"
               FontAttributes="{Binding LabelTextFontStyle}" />
    </StackLayout>
    <Frame BorderColor="Black"
           CornerRadius="7"
           Padding="5,0"
           Margin="0,-3,0,0"
           HasShadow="false">
        <Entry x:Name="mainEntry"
               Keyboard="{Binding KeybdType}"
               Placeholder="{Binding EntryPlaceHolder}"
               TextColor="Black"
               FontSize="Default"
               HeightRequest="{Binding EntryHeight}" />
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Next, I want to switch focus from the Entry to a "next" element when the user taps the DONE button, so I do:

```
    namespace Mynamespace.Components
    {
        public partial class FormEntry : StackLayout
        {
            public VisualElement NextFocus
            {
                get { return (VisualElement)GetValue(NextFocusProperty); }
                set { SetValue(NextFocusProperty, value); }
            }

            public static readonly BindableProperty NextFocusProperty =
                BindableProperty.Create(nameof(NextFocus),
                                        typeof(VisualElement),
                                        typeof(FormEntry),
                                        null,
                                     Xamarin.Forms.BindingMode.OneWay);

            public FormEntry()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                BindingContext = this;

                mainEntry.Completed += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (NextFocus != null)
                    {
                        NextFocus.Focus();
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Next, in order for a FormEntry to be the target of NextFocus, I tried adding

```
    this.Focused += (s,e) => { mainEntry.Focus(); };
```

to the constructor, but the handler is never called, and I also tried overriding

```
    public new void Focus() {
        mainEntry.Focus();
    }
```

but this method is never called. Layout classes are descended from VisualElement so they should inherit Focused. Is there something about Layout objects that I'm missing? I could understand that Layout objects aren't usually the target of focus, but the event handler is supposedly there so I ought to be able to use it.

Here's an example of how I utilize the FormEntry on a login screen:

```
    <!-- Email -->
    <controls:FormEntry x:Name="usernameEntry"
                        Margin="25,40,25,0"
                        IsRequired="true"
                        EntryHeight="40"
                        KeybdType="Email"
                        NextFocus="{x:Reference passwordEntry}"
                        LabelText="{il8n:Translate Emailorusername}"
                        EntryPlaceHolder="{il8n:Translate EnterUsername}">
    </controls:FormEntry>

    <!-- Password -->
    <controls:FormEntry x:Name="passwordEntry"
                        Margin="25,0,25,0"
                        IsRequired="true"
                        EntryHeight="40"
                        LabelText="{il8n:Translate Password}"
                        EntryPlaceHolder="{il8n:Translate EnterPassword}" />
```

Comment: Note: the code above works fine if NextFocus refers to a simple Entry component. I just can't figure out how to catch the Focused event for the FormEntry component.

Comment: Can you provide entire demo here? Because I am not particularly clear about your problem.

Comment: In the example snippet I have included already, the login screen, my problem is this: how do I enable the user to switch from the "usernameEntry" FormEntry component to the "passwordEntry" FormEntry component with a press of the keyboard DONE button? If "passwordEntry" is simply an Entry, instead of my FormEntry component, everything works: focus is switched from "usernameEntry" to "passwordEntry"; I can't get a FormEntry to receive focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have get the nextfocus element, you can get mainEntry from nextfocus, like this:

```
 public FormEntry ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = this;

        mainEntry.Completed += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (NextFocus != null)
            {
                FormEntry formentry = (FormEntry)NextFocus;
                Entry entry = formentry.mainEntry;
                entry.Focus();
            }
        };
    }
```

Then you can find you will get focus.

Comment: I'm going to go with this answer. I had considered it already, but it doesn't cover the case where the next control is something other than a FormEntry. But now I've considered that in a mobile app, it probably doesn't make sense for other type of components to receive focus (as in Windows, for example).

Comment: Could you help to reach out to the solution for the next code? How to fire the Focused event for the labels...
   
 <StackLayout>
        <Entry Text="Entry0" TabIndex="0" IsTabStop="True" Grid.Row="0"></Entry>
        <Label Text="lable1" TabIndex="1" IsTabStop="True" Grid.Row="1" Focused="Label_Focused"></Label>
        <Entry Text="Entry2" TabIndex="2" IsTabStop="True" Grid.Row="2"></Entry>
        <Label Text="lable3" TabIndex="3" IsTabStop="True" Grid.Row="3"  Focused="Label_Focused"></Label>
    </StackLayout>